# The latency of python PeeWee object save function for sqlite become too slow accidentally

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, nvidia, peewee

I am writing one program to record the gps information for the frame read by opencv. I use PeeWee to do ORM. Normally the database insert operation cost < 8ms, but sometimes it become > 100ms.
I don't know why it happens , so I need some helps to troubleshooting it.

```
import json
import cv2
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import time
import sqlite3
import pynmea2
import uuid
from peewee import *
from loguru import logger
import os


db_another = SqliteDatabase('robu_another3.db',pragmas={"journal_mode": "wal","cache_size":-1024*64,"page_size":32768,"synchronous":"normal","temp_store":"memory"}, timeout=40)

class LandscapeFrameTest(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(verbose_name='时间戳', null=False)
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'frame_records_test'
        database = db_another
        order_by = ('timestamp',)

happen = 0
happen_10 = 0
happen_20 = 0
happen_100 = 0
all_time = 0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video2", cv2.CAP_V4L)
image_width = 1920
image_height = 1080
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, image_width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, image_height)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 10)           #帧数
print('Opened: ',cap.isOpened())

db_another.drop_tables([LandscapeFrameTest])
db_another.create_tables([LandscapeFrameTest])

while True:
    ret, frame_read = cap.read()
    print(frame_read.shape)
    time_now = datetime.now()
    timestr_now_str = time_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    print(timestr_now_str)
    frame_object = {"photo_time":timestr_now_str}
    start_p = time.time()
    f = LandscapeFrameTest(timestamp = frame_object['photo_time'])
    f.save(force_insert=True)
    end_p = time.time()
    framedb_cost = (end_p-start_p)*1000
    all_time = all_time+1
    logger.debug(db_another.get_primary_keys('frame_records_test'))
    if framedb_cost > 100:
        happen_100 = happen_100 +1
    elif framedb_cost > 20:
        happen_20 = happen_20 +1
    elif framedb_cost > 10:
        happen_10 = happen_10 +1
    logger.debug('Cost {} For {} ,Happen 100 {},Happen 20 {},Happen 10 {},After {}.'.format(framedb_cost,frame_object['photo_time'],happen_100,happen_20,happen_10,all_time))
    if framedb_cost > 100:
        break
    frame_nums = LandscapeFrameTest.select().count()
    logger.debug("Handle Frame Database  Frame All Count  {}".format(frame_nums))
```

I run the programer in Nvidia AGX Orin. After 10938, the latency become 274 ms(The output as bellow).

2023-02-19 07:47:07.216 | DEBUG    | **main**::63 - Handle Frame Database  Frame All Count  10936
(1080, 1920, 3)
2023-02-19 07:47:07.311356
2023-02-19 07:47:07.312 | DEBUG    | **main**::52 - ['id']
2023-02-19 07:47:07.312 | DEBUG    | **main**::59 - Cost 0.9157657623291016 For 2023-02-19 07:47:07.311356 ,Happen 100 0,Happen 20 3,Happen 10 0,After 10937.
2023-02-19 07:47:07.313 | DEBUG    | **main**::63 - Handle Frame Database  Frame All Count  10937
(1080, 1920, 3)
2023-02-19 07:47:07.411241
2023-02-19 07:47:07.685 | DEBUG    | **main**::52 - ['id']
2023-02-19 07:47:07.686 | DEBUG    | **main**::59 - Cost 274.2321491241455 For 2023-02-19 07:47:07.411241 ,Happen 100 1,Happen 20 3,Happen 10 0,After 10938.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why this might occur, my suggestion would be to run with a profiler and see if you can pin-point where in the call-stack the slowness is occurring. I assume your data is uniform, so that it is completely arbitrary whether an insert takes 8ms or 100ms? It could be something to do with the disk IO scheduler, sqlite reorganizing the btree or indexes, the OS flushing pages, sqlite synchronous setting, etc. You might try setting sqlite pragma synchronous=0 and seeing if that changes anything?

Comment: I changed the synchronous  to 0, but it also happens after 1717 times as the output bellow. 
2023-02-19 06:22:35.857410
2023-02-19 06:22:35.986 | DEBUG    | __main__:<module>:124 - Cost 128.54909896850586 For 2023-02-19 06:22:35.857410 ,Happen 100 0,Happen 20 0,Happen 10 0,After 1717.

Comment: Like I said - I assume you're hitting some kind of disk operation eventually. You can profile to verify but it's probably just going to show the delay occurring in a sqlite operation of some sort. One other thing you might try is to mmap your database using the mmap_size pragma: https://www.sqlite.org/mmap.html but overall if you need real-time or low-latency I'd suggest asking on the sqlite forums once you've determined for sure it's a sqlite thing.